# In Js How to wrap all last childred of an oject tree?

Tags: javascript

Just wanted to write some recursion but can't check if the child is in fact some finite thing, when checking throught jQuery.isPlainObject , just getting a saparate letters as a childs , like I want "this is error message" - to be a last child , but can't detect it

Comment: Can you post some code to make it clearer to us what exactly you're asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shot in the dark here:

```
typeof "hello" === "string"

typeof {} === "object"
```

With this, you can tell if the child is a string ("this is error message") or another type of object.